# error: Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material

In my project, I'm using angular 6 with Spring-boot and what I want to know is how to resolve the error called

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
>   at Object../node_modules/util/util.js (util.js:109)

In my `util.js` the error is highlighted as follows but I don't know to resolve this.

```
if (process.env.NODE_DEBUG) {
  var debugEnv = process.env.NODE_DEBUG;
  debugEnv = debugEnv.replace(/[|\\{}()[\]^$+?.]/g, '\\$&')
    .replace(/\*/g, '.*')
    .replace(/,/g, '$|^')
    .toUpperCase();
  debugEnvRegex = new RegExp('^' + debugEnv + '$', 'i');
}
```

[image]

> Note: Recently I have installed material community components package using `npm install material-community-components`

There are similer questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182398/using-ng2-material-gives-error-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined) but nothing helped me yet. This is my [package.json](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkeeym?file=package.json) file.

Comment: Can you please add package.json file?

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have added below code of block in polyfills.ts & issue resolve:

```
(window as any).process = {
  env: { DEBUG: undefined },
};
```